# Trying to create a list that contains a Class I created and get names for each instance from Database

Tags: c#

I have a table in a database that I want to get into a list.  I have a Class I created that has a string or int value that corresponds to each field in the database.  (The class doesn’t have any methods, it just holds data.)

Using a reader I’m able to get each record from the database and add it to the list, but each instance of the Class in the list always has the same name so I can’t access it with the IndexOf method.  Each record in the database has a unique name, and I’d like to use that unique name to name each instance of the class I insert in the C# List.

I’ve seen talk of using reflection, but also reading it’s not a good way to go.  Most answers lean towards Activator.CreateInstance, but I’m not finding an example that works, and I can see how I can reference the instance of the class to then define the members.

I have a string name, that came from a database, and was user defined elsewhere, but I can’t duplicate that record in a list, as a class, so I can reference members of the class without having to constantly open the database.

Alternatively, a way to find a record in a list where a member of the class in the list is a certain value would work, and I can have every class in the list have the same name.  The examples I’m finding for lists use int and strings as examples, so there aren’t any members to look at.

Comment: Index your unique name and add a property to the class to house this name.  Before you add the new list item make sure you populate the name.

Comment: By index I mean:  reader["Name of column containing unique value"] sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: Alterantely you could use a dictionary which you could use to add items based on your unique column and then index the dictionary.  Eg. someDictionary["a unique value"] to get your tuple/row out

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  The dictionary is working.  I was thinking of only two string values in a dictionary, not a string and a class I created.  In my case I'm now using an int and my custom class and it looks like it's going to work great.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There are some possibilities:

1. Create a `Dictionary<string, Class>`. In the key, you put you unique name:

   ```
   Dictionary<string, Class> d = new Dictionary<string, Class>();
   d.Add("unique name from db", instanceOfClass);

   Class c = d["unique name from db"];
   ```
2. Add the unique field as property in your class
3. Create another unique identifier, like a primary key or something like that.